# Clone is stuck at "POST git-upload-pack" while behind corporate webproxy

Tags: git

I want to clone https://git.rancher.io/charts from my work computer (windows) which sits behind a proxy. The proxy is configured as follows

```
http.https://git.rancher.io.proxy=http://:@webproxy.intra:8080
http.https://git.rancher.io.sslverify=true
http.https://git.rancher.io.com.sslbackend=schannel
```

However the clone hangs during `POST git-upload-pack`

```sh
git clone https://git.rancher.io/charts rancher-charts -v --progress
Cloning into 'rancher-charts'...
POST git-upload-pack (gzip 1125 to 631 bytes)
```

I can make the clone work, when restricting the depth:

```sh
$ git clone https://git.rancher.io/charts rancher-charts -v --progress --depth 1
Cloning into 'rancher-charts'...
POST git-upload-pack (190 bytes)
POST git-upload-pack (199 bytes)
remote: Counting objects: 4593, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2490/2490), done.
Receiving objects:  75% (3445/4593)eused 3985 (delta 2011)eceiving objects:  73% (3353/4593)
Receiving objects: 100% (4593/4593), 4.22 MiB | 10.96 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2223/2223), done.
Updating files: 100% (5986/5986), done.
```

Any explication why this might happen? and how to be able to clone without `--depth 1`

Comment: I would suspect that the office proxy is mangling the requests somehow, maybe it has a restriction on request size.

Comment: http proxies are notorious for corrupting data. If at all possible, bypass it entirely (e.g., use ssh to clone).

Comment: @torek sure but this is often not possible in corporate environments i.e. shh is no option either.